# Virtual host creation while code deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

i am using aws code deploy for my application deployment.In this ,i have used virtual host creation code inside appspec.yml file.It is working properly.But it s executing second deployment also.How i can prevent this.This is my appspec code

```
BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/create_virtualhost
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
    - location: scripts/start_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

> create_virtualhost.sh File

```
 echo '<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin test@demo.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/demo.com"
    ServerName demo.com
    ServerAlias www.demo.com
</VirtualHost>' >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpdnew.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

as i'm aware you can't limit hooks being execute only once. Only application stop hook will not run on the first time deployment. so you have to handle those in scripts. Maybe you can do something like this

create_virtualhost.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e /etc/httpd/conf/httpdnew.conf ]
then
    echo "vhost exists..skipping.."
else
    echo '<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin test@demo.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/demo.com"
    ServerName demo.com
    ServerAlias www.demo.com
    </VirtualHost>' >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpdnew.conf
fi
```

Comment: httpdnew.conf file always exist...so i can not use this condition

Comment: as for you're question. you're creating it on the first time deployment right? after that you don't need to create the file. if that's what you want this will do it. AND i'm unclear what you mean by "httpdnew.conf file always exist", are you trying to replace this file in the first place?

Comment: actually it is 'httpd.conf' not httpdnew.conf. It created while installing lampp in linux.ie the httpd.conf file already in the folder before deployment